# Booting from a local ISO

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, mount

I've got a remote server which has Ubuntu preinstalled, so now I'm trying to install RHEL Server with JavaKVM. The problem arises when I try to boot from an image on a disk sdb, partition 1. 
I've partitioned sdb1 as an id 83 Linux partition and created ext4 file system where I've put my rhel iso file in the /iso folder. It's mounted and it can be seen in fstab. 
I've configured my 40_custom file to look like this:

```
 set isofile="/iso/rhel-server-7.3-x86_64-dvd.iso"
      loopback loop (hd1,1)$isofile
      linux (loop)/isolinux/vmlinuz boot=isolinux iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject
      initrd (loop)/isolinux/initrd.img
```

I can see the menu entry inside GRUB, but when i decide to mount it, it's simply stuck on a black screen.

Comment: Try boot=casper on the linux line.  That's what I use for Ubuntu isos, although Ubuntu's initrd is compressed.

Comment: This is actually on topic here, so you're welcome to leave it if you like. However, you are more likely to get an answer on our sister site, [unix.se] since this requires some experience with RH isos and not only Ubuntu, if there's something special about the RH. If you do want to move it, I can migrate it for you if you like, or you can delete and repost there. Up to you.

Comment: Getting drive & path correct is an on going issue. Drive may change. I almost always have that issue with flash drives, my sdf becomes sdb on reboot.  You path probably is `loopback loop (hd1,1)/iso/$isofile`